# How do I find out the IP address of my Crostini container?

Tags: google-chrome-os, crostini

I'm running a Node.js server on Crostini, and trying to access it from and Android browser running on the same Chrome OS device via localhost:8080 doesn't work.

I've tried `penguin.linux.test:8080`, but that didn't work either. Looks like the Android container didn't get the right DNS settings.

So how do I get the IP address of the Linux container? `ifconfig` is not installed and `apt install` fails to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even easier is just to use `hostname -I`. This will output the ip address and nothing else

Answer (score 4):

`ifconfig` is deprecated. Use instead:

```
ip addr show
```

[image: ip addr show on Crostini]

Comment: can you give a little insight to why/when ifconfig was depr.? seems to be still part of net-tools when installed on newer versions