# Figwheel-main not connecting to websocket

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I'm using linux in a ChromeOs, so to access my linux localhost I go to `penguin.linux.test`.

I'm trying to setup figwheel-main, but I'm not able to set the websocket as penguin.linux.test instead of localhost. I'm getting the following in the devtools console:

```
websocket.js:283 WebSocket connection to 'ws://penquin.linux.test:9500/figwheel-connect?fwprocess=d0e7c5&fwbuild=dev&fwsid=a3177bc7-ece2-46e3-a8d3-6553eac8a6e9' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
[goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined
```

I followed the [documentation](https://figwheel.org/config-options#connect-url) but I couldn't connect to the websocket by neither changing the connect-url or the config-hostname. I can see my file `target/public/cljs-out/dev/cljsc_opts.edn` is contains

```
#:figwheel.repl{connect-url "ws://penquin.linux.test:9500/figwheel-connect?fwprocess=d0e7c5&fwbuild=dev"}
```

I used to do it in lein-fighweel by editing the file `resources/public/js/out/figwheel/connect.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it with the following configuration in my `dev.cljs.edn`

```
^{:connect-url "ws://100.115.92.205:9500/figwheel-connect"}
```

This is the ip address of the Crostini container. You can find it by running `ip addr show` as pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215515/3646180).